# pulseaudio volume much over 100%

Tags: pulseaudio

How can I get the volume much over 100%. Sometimes the sound is not loud enought otherwise. I've tried using `pavucontrol` but that only allows me to go up to 125% (so with doing both playback and output to 125% that's 156%).

Comment: meta told me to post questions and answer them myself (this realy took me some time to figure out :)). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pactl set-sink-volume x 130%`. Replace x by the relevant sink volume (bash completion may help. For me 0 corresponds to the hdmi output and 1 to the analog output). You can also use +30% instead of 130% to make the volume louder.